# Why does jQuery Mobile use data-role attributes instead of classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

This may be a naive question, but I'm learning jQuery Mobile and unsure why everything is related to a `data-role` attribute. It seems that even times when the role is related to the style, they are using `data-role` over `class`

I understand that for semantics, `data-role` makes sense in a lot of cases but it just seems to be abused here. Wouldn't that kind of lookup also be slower?

Why do they use `data-role` over *class*?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: It's unlikely it's due to speed. It may be better to edit your question so that instead of asking "is it faster?", it just asks "why do they do it this way?" (to which "it is faster" may be a valid answer)

Comment: It's probably slower (but by how much, and does it even matter?) than classes *for CSS*, as class selectors are likely more optimized - however, they perform *different* roles so choose the correct one.

Comment: That was my original phrasing ;) I thought it was too subjective. I may just have to change it back.

Comment: @user2246674 I would think speed doesn't matter for desktop in most cases, but on mobile you can't always be so lucky, where even amount of DOM nodes can slow down a site

Comment: @DaveStein That's what performance tests are for: "by how much, and does it even matter?" Unless a *lookup* is performed on the data value, there ought to be no performance issue here at all. Accessing the class (or data attribute) for a *specific element* should have identical performance characteristics.

Comment: @user2246674 I'd do a JS perf now if I wasn't at a talk and this is gnawing at me ;) Also by looking at source it seems they frequently look up by data via jquery `$([data-])`

Comment: @DaveStein Is the selector bound to a specific element or set of elements? A small set of elements will take a small[er amount of] time to scan, even with a naive selector implementation. If not run frequently .. (cost = time * freq)

Comment: Relevant: http://jsperf.com/class-vs-data-attribute-selector-performance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Why `data`

They could simply use `role` as an attribute (like other frameworks do), but this would make 
the resulting HTML invalid. Therefore a `data-` is added to every attribute name.

#### Why not classes

I think the main reason for that is to separate view from logic as far as it is possible. In larger projects, CSS and JavaScript are not written by the same person.

Comment: I'm watching a demo right now and adding a `data-role` automatically added styles. Was this because of the demo-writer or the default jquery mobile styles? It seemed to be the latter. I agree with everything you said so that's where I got thrown off in this presentation.

Comment: I've upvoted you but just need that extra clarification before I mark as answer ;)

Comment: @DaveStein The difference is in the intent. CSS classes suggest styling/appearance whereas `data-` attributes can suggest features/functionality (paging, navigation, etc.). Those features may in turn apply styling, but the features are the primary focus.

Comment: To add to that, they look by `data-role` for semantics and then add classes at that moment, which then do the styling. Doesn't make as much sense to do classes AND data if it has to go to data no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

It provides a lot of control over powerful styling techniques especially when combined with jquery ui. I use jquery mobile, I used their tool to easily make a theme roller and now when I use elements like data-role-header, footer listview. I have great looking pages with no effort. There are hundreds of data-role attributes you can bring into your code to easily create uniform, user friendly pages. I personally like the data-role - page attribute to create multiple views in a single HTML page. They are easy to use so the best way to learn about them is to play with them.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I do lots of work with jQuery UI but never use `data-`. I know that they assign data in different ways, aside from putting into the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the explanation of data-roles [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/).

`data-role` attribute is used to control the behaviour of the widget of element. For example in case of button you can use `input type="button"` (no `data-role="button"` attribute required in this case, as this is standard behaviour of this element) but you can use `a` element, and then you need to explicitly provide it:

```
<a href="" data-role="button"></a>
```

So for me it's rather useful solution, as buttons behavior on mobile devices can be same for different elements. You just need to provide `data-role` attribute, and jQuery will do the rest for you.

This is the quotation from main jQuery Mobile website:

> jQuery mobile framework takes the "write less, do more" mantra to the
>   next level: Instead of writing unique apps for each mobile device or
>   OS, the jQuery mobile framework allows you to design a single
>   highly-branded web site or application that will work on all popular
>   smartphone, tablet, and desktop platforms.

They want to style every control you have in the same way, so `write less, do more` approach is fulfilled. So jQuery Mobile adds same styling for all elements with the same role to make things look the same way, but it doesn't mean you can't change it. It just means that they care about good look of your website, and they are aware that every button should be similar to others.

Also the page I mentioned earlier says:

> The jQuery Mobile framework uses HTML5 data- attributes to allow for
>   markup-based initialization and configuration of widgets.

So you are reading HTML and you know how elements will behave without looking to CSS file - which I think is cool if you're not front-end dev. Of course front-end dev can overwrite CSS, but he must follow the rules, e.g. if `data-inline` is set to `true` he should style it regarding that elements must naturally follow this rule (be `inline`).

Comment: This isn't asking what data-role is used for - it's asking why they use data-role instead of classes.

Comment: @Carlos yeah I'm curious why the `data-role` seems to handle function AND style same time

Answer (score 0):

jQueryMobile adds a load event handler to the page, which processes the DOM looking for various data-xxx attributes.  When it finds those, it does more than just stylize the elements.

In many cases it creates a type of widget tied to the data-role.  For example, a <div data-role="header"> is turned into a toolbar widget, the creation of which may extensively modify the DOM within that element.

For some of the simpler widgets, like buttons, folks have seen that not much happens other than some classes get added, so why not just shortcut the process and do that directly?  That can work, but it isn't future-proof.  At different points in history, different versions of jQM had created buttons with different DOM structures.  So I personally think it's best not to shortcut jQM, and let it process the data-attributes as it sees fit.

That being said, it would still have been possible to create widgets identified by classes rather than data-attributes, which was how people used to do these things before jQM.  But then there might be an expectation that there would be CSS associated with those classes as well.  Use of the data- attributes makes it clear that this is a structural/role thing rather than just styling.